# Search in data base Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

Have data table `Programmer` and `Lang`

- `Programmer` rows: `ProjectID`, `Person`
- `Lang` row: `Id`, `name`
- In Programer have data: 1,John; 3,Mike; 2, Tommy
- In Lang have: 1, Java; 2 ,C#; 3, Python

How to get data like this tale:

- Java John
- C# Mike
- Python Tommy

Using Mysql and PHP, I no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy this::

Select  name, Person from Programmer p  inner join Lang l on (p.ProjectID=l.ID)

If you need according to the row occurance in the table::

```
Select nL.name,nP.Person 
from
(select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, Person
from
 (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, Programmer order by rank) as nP
inner join

(select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank_1’, name
from
 (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, Lang order by rank_1) as nL on (nP.rank=nL.rank_1)
```

Comment: This only work if programmer and lang id is same, but in my table programmer id can be 3.1.2 and lang 3.2.1 and i must search not comparable id of line equate or not

Comment: u want them to be joined on the basis of their occurance in the table??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article that taught me how to search:

http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Most of the work will be done using SQL and indexes, using something called fulltext searching.

QUICK START:

You will need to index the columns you wish to search in your database, then use the `MATCH()` and `AGAINST()` methods to perform more "better" searches than using `%LIKE%`.